# The Narrator ignores AutomationProperties.Name when it is in scan mode

Tags: xaml, uwp, accessibility, textblock, narrator

In my `UWP` app I have TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock Text="Text0" 
           AutomationProperties.Name="Text1" />
```

The Narrator reads only the `Text` properties in the scan mode ignoring `AutomationProperties.Name`.
`AutomationProperties.LabeledBy` aslo doesn't work.

Why does the Narrator ignore `AutomationProperties.Name` when it in scan mode (CapsLock + Space) for `TextBlock`?

Thanks.

Comment: When I use your code and set Narrator in the scan mode, it can not read the `Text` of the `TextBlock`. Could you tell us your OS version of your Windows and your VS SDK  in here?

Comment: @Jayden Gu - MSFT, I have OS Windows Version 1703 (Build 15063.483) and VS 2017. Narrator ignore AutomationProperties.Name only when it in the scan mode (CapsLock + Space).

Comment: @JaydenGu-MSFT Was this ever fixed?